# Java Dynamic Names

Tags: java, android, dynamic, names

I know, that Java doesn't have a pre-processor, so some stuff is more or less impossible in java.

Is there really **NO** way to fill those arrays with dynamic names in a loop?
I'd like to have something like:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
earnTvs[i]=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.INSERT_GREAT_TRICK_HERE("earn"+i+"Tv"));
}
```

instead of

```
    earnTvs[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.earn1Tv);
    earnTvs[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.earn2Tv);
    earnTvs[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.earn3Tv);
    earnTvs[3] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.earn4Tv);
    earnTvs[4] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.earn5Tv);
    timeTvs[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time1Tv);
    ...
    ownTvs[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.own1Tv);
    ...
    costTvs[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.build1Tv);
    ...
    buyBtns[0] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buy1Bt);
    ...
    progressBars[0] = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prog1pB);
    ...
    buildBtns[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.build1Bt);
    ...
```

Or is there any kinky trick, that can be used?

Comment: Is reflection of any help? It would seem to be what you're looking for, more or less.

Comment: `getResources().getIdentifier()` is what you're looking for

Comment: I see that return an int.
How would I have to use that in my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like that:

```
final int[] earnTvsId = new int[] {R.id.earn1Tv, R.id.earn2Tv, R.id.earn3Tv, R.id.earn4Tv ...};
for(int i = 0; i < earnTvsId.length; ++i){
    earnTvs[i] = (TextView) findViewById(earnTvsId[i]);
}
```

If you want to use the `getIdentifier()` method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_TEXTVIEWS; ++i) {
    final int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("earn" + i + "Tv", "id", getPackageName());
    earnTvs[i] = (TextView) findViewById(resId);
}
```

Comment: I think the OP doesn't know what goes into the array. He'd like it to be all dynamic.

Comment: I would not use reflections in this case. It is only my opinion but reflections make thinks difficult if you want to use Android Proguard and other stuff.

Comment: Yea, that would be a little bit better at least, but it seems like I could use reflections, I just dont get how!

Comment: @user3646267 I added the second possibility to my answer.

Comment: Okay, that seems to be exactly the idea I was looking for.
I realise how bad that is if the names of those TextViews changes, as no IDE will be able to refactor that correctly, but in my case it helps me out a lot!

Answer (score 0):

With reflection. But I'm not sure if reflections are good here...

```
Class<?> idClass = R.id.getClass();
Field field = idClass.getField("earn" + i + "Tv");
TextView textView = (TextView) field.get(R.id);
```

Comment: I guess it's R.id.class in the first line, isn't it?
Also there is a expression expected at (R.id);

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection for this purpose, but that's known to be slow on Android (especially older versions) and for the specified use case pretty unmaintainable; what if the ID's change? You'd have to make your changes in 2 places (XML & code) rather than let your IDE handle propagating the change.

If it's boilerplate you're annoyed with, perhaps you should take a look at [Android Annotations](http://androidannotations.org/). It uses compile-time annotations & an annotation processor to help you reduce boilerplate code.

Comment: Even if it's unmaintainable in this case, I'd like to learn about it, but I didn't manage to make it work. Could you show me, how it would look like in this case?