# Set string as button id programmatically

Tags: android

I have buttons with ids button1, button2, button3, button4,...

Is there a way to call button using string? For example:

```
    int buttonNumber = 1;
    String buttonId= "button" + buttonNumber;
    findViewById(R.id.buttonId).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28951702/java-dynamic-names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Resources](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) class has a method [getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
public int getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage)
```

Which returns the integer of the specified resource name, type & package.

Answer (score -2):

There is no way that you can set a `String` as an id for your view. But you can use `setTag()` method which accepts any object as tag like string etc. and it can be used instead of id for getting view in a layout.

using :

```
view.findViewWithTag("string");
```

check this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewWithTag(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Did you understand what the OP asked?